# prepend fadeOut transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a transition for my `prepend()` function. Every time an item is prepended inside the `#instafeed` div, it should fade out first, then prepend, and finally it will fade in. The objective is to make the prepend transition as smooth as possible, so the user can't see the item change until it fades in again.

The problem is that even setting the time, the item change is happening before the fade out.

*Wanted:* `fadeOut ==> prepend ==> fadeIn`

*What is happening:* `prepend ==> fadeOut ==> fadeIn`

```
$(function($){  
    $('.thebutton').click(function(){
        $('#instafeed').fadeOut(3000).prepend($('#instafeed div:last')).fadeIn(3000);
    });

    setInterval( function(){
        $('.thebutton').trigger('click');
    }, 9000);   
});
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the `prepend()` and `fadeIn()` in the callback of the `fadeOut()` so they are executed when the animation ends. Try this:

```
$('.thebutton').click(function(){
    $('#instafeed').fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $(this).prepend($('#instafeed div:last')).fadeIn(3000)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

should be called in the callback function:

```js
$('#instafeed').fadeOut(3000, function(){
   $(this).prepend($('#instafeed div:last')).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use callback handlers of [fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
$('#instafeed').fadeOut(3000, function(){

   $( this ).prepend( $('#instafeed div:last') ).fadeIn(3000);

});
```

Comment: Note that `prepend()` doesn't have a callback function as it's not asynchronous.